# yo generator takes forever

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I"m following [this tutorial](http://tagtree.tv/yeoman-generator) , everything is installed and/or up to date but when I do yo generator it seems to stuck there and I can't know why or how to fix it.

[image: Screenshot :]

Comment: This is what i get when I stop it manually :

Promise rejected with value: true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check rights or try run with sudo.